# How to set default terminal of gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any way that I can set default terminal in gnuplot?
I am trying to set the default terminal to x11 but it is always aqua when start up.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way I know is to add a line to the `.gnuplot` (or `gnuplotrc` or `gnuplot.ini`) file that is loaded on startup. (This file may live in your home directory or elsewhere depending on your gnuplot version / configuration, and you can see where it lives with the `show loadpath` command.) Here is the line to add:

```
set term x11
```

The commands in this file are executed before any others when gnuplot is run.

Comment: The file now being named gnuplotrc or gnuplot.ini, and located in ${gnuplot_dir}\share\ (try `show loadpath`to see where it is located).

Comment: Thanks, @PJ127, specifically for "show loadpath". andyras: Please consider updating the answer. Gnuplot does not read rc/ini files from the home dir any more.

Answer (score 1):

While [@andyras' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19989463/9076659) works, there is still this notification about the old terminal when starting new session - I wanted to change `windows` to `wxt`: when I changed my `gnuplotrc` to have `wxt` the greeting message still mentioned `windows`:

```
PS C:\Users\Ev> gnuplot
...
Terminal type is now 'windows'
...
```

Although it was indeed using `wxt` now:

```
gnuplot> show t

   terminal type is wxt 0 enhanced
```

I found the way to fix it in readme in the folder with the program, in my case `C:\Program Files\gnuplot\README-Windows.txt`:

> If GNUTERM is defined, it is used as the name of the terminal type to be used.

So instead of the files, I set up the env var `GNUTERM`.